# Openfiler as KVM guest does not recognize drives

Tags: kvm-virtualization, openfiler

Team,

I am using openfiler as a KVM guest, I have provisioned virtual drives and can see them when I login to the openfiler cli and run fdisk -l. I cannot however configure them from the openfiler GUI.

I tried adding raw, I tried pvcreate, I tried writing a partition (I have all three types of devices on the system) they show up in fdisk -l however they don't show up in the web page. Please advise.

CODE: As requested the output of  virsh dumpxml openfiler ALSO fdisk -l from openfiler are available at:
http://www.kartik.com/openfiler.html
I apologize but I don't know how to format code in these posts.

Regards,

Comment: Please attach "virsh dumpxml guestname" to your question.

Comment: CODE: As requested the output of  virsh dumpxml openfiler ALSO fdisk -l from openfiler are available at:
http://www.kartik.com/openfiler.html
I apologize but I don't know how to format code in these posts.

Comment: I'm using open filer, but you can try to use bus-type virtio-scsi when you add the virtual disk to your guest, http://www.felso.net/running-windows-on-linux-with-qemukvm-using-virtual-machine-manager/

Comment: [root@nfs-openfiler qemu]# virsh define openfiler.xml
error: Failed to define domain from openfiler.xml
error: unsupported configuration: unknown disk bus type 'virtio-scsi'

[root@nfs-openfiler qemu]#

Comment: try to change bus type using virt-manager

Comment: change bus-type to what?

Comment: scsi, in this way the name of disk in guest will be sda and sdb and so on as in physical server http://www.ovirt.org/Features/Virtio-SCSI